# How to create cyclic enum definition?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create these two enum classes

```
import static B.B1;

public enum A {
    
    A1(B1);

    private A(B b) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

```
import static A.A1;

public enum B {
    
    B1(A1);
    
    private B(A a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

but when i run this code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A1.ordinal();
    }
}
```

i get the following output

```
null
B1
```

instead of

```
A1
B1
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: "how can I solve this problem?" What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: This is surpising to me. I know it has to do with the initialization order, but it seems flaky to me that the output depends on which of A and B was referred to first by a caller. If I switch to `B1.ordinal();` in the main-function, the output changes to `null A1`.

Comment: @marstran enums are (mostly) just syntactic sugar for public static final instances. If one instance refers to another class during initialization, the other class will start being initialized; if the other class refers back to the first class, class loader can't start initializing the first one again, so it has two options: throw an exception, or continue, allowing the second class to observe the current (albeit not final) state of the first. I would say an exception would be preferable, but that's not what Java does.

Comment: @AndyTurner Right, agree. Or even a compile error (although I guess the compiler won't be able to find all cycles of arbitary size).

Comment: An alternative is to lazily construct [EnumMaps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) to hold your associations, instead of using constructors and fields in the enums to define the associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solve this inside the constructors. It's a fundamental limitation of the way classes are initialized: if a class cyclically refers to itself during initialization, it sees the current state of the class, which may mean that `final` fields can be observed to be `null`, even though you can see them as non-null later.

Instead, you can have a method on the enums to get the "other":

```
public enum A {
    A1;

    B other() { return B.B1; }
}

public enum B {
    B1;

    A other() { return A.A1; }
}
```

Now, `A1.other()` will give you `B1`; and `B1.other()` will give you `A1`.

Comment: To add to this: If you need to return different instances for each enum member, you can create an abstract method on the enum, and then implement it on each enum member.

Comment: If the body of the `other` function contains heavy processing of the enum variable how could I avoid to re-execute it on every call of `other` function?

Comment: @Subia you shouldn't be doing really heavy processing in an enum's method. Trivially, you could cache the "heavy" value in some sort of external map.